# How to `scaler.transform` result of `model.predict` with multiple input LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, preprocessor

Here is my code:

```python
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), :])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, -1])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

look_back = 20


df = pd.read_csv('stock.csv')

signal_data = df[["close", "open", "high", "low", "volume"]].values.astype('float32')


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
signal_data = scaler.fit_transform(signal_data)

train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size
train = signal_data[0:train_size]
test = signal_data[train_size:]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)
...
model.add(LSTM)
```

When I perform `predict = model.predict(x_test)` and `scaler.transfrom(predict)`, an error occurs:

```
on-broadcastable output operand with shape (5,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (5,5)
```

The dataset has 5 features. When I use `model.predict()`, the output shape is (n, 1), but `scaler.transform` needs (n, 5) shape.

If I `transform` before `model.predict`, I can't `transform` because dimension is 3,

and if I `transform` after `model.predict`, shape is (n, 1) So I can't `transform`.

So, I can't apply `scaler.transform` on `model.predict()`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm wondering if the result of `model.predict` is expanded in two dimensions using `np.ones` and the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is little bit unclear, but based on the information you have provided, I am putting forth my observations.

You have already transformed your entire dataset using the below code:

```
signal_data = scaler.fit_transform(signal_data)
```

So, you need not transform your `x_test` again. You can directly call the `model.predict` on it. If you are testing on a new data, which hasn't been transformed as above, then you will have to transform it. Make sure that this new testing dataset too has 5 features in it (and not 3) as your model has been trained on 5 features.

Lastly, after the time series prediction is over, if you wish to transform back your scaled data to it's original version, you may use [`inverse_transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform) function of your `MinMaxScaler` instance.